# Como formatar a aparencia de um link nas redes sociais?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eu gostaria de formatar a publicação de um link como é feito com spotfy e outros sites grande.

Atualmente apenas mostra o link do site e gostaria de deixar tudo formato com imagem + texto.

Aqui está uma imagem que resume minha dúvida.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pode consultar aqui toda a documentação sobre esse assunto: http://ogp.me/

As opções mais normais de usar são estas:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Titulo que deseja" />
<meta property="og:url" content="https://www.exemplo.com/" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Descrição que quer que apareça" />
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.exemplo.com/images/icon-1024.png" />
```

Comment: Obrigado! agora sim está todo formatado tudo de bom :)